# Image Encryption: Convert Image Pixel Data into Byte Values

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, rgb

I'm attempting to encrypt the content of a file, in this case a png, and not the actual file itself. This way I can see the difference between ECB and CBC encrpytion (example photos [here:](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/ecb-penguin).

My intuition: I'm unsure if this is the best or even correct approach but my logic is to take the pixel data from the png and store it into an array. Then take the array and convert to a byte array. This way I can encrypt it using either ecb or cbc and then simply reverse the process afterwards.

**My attempted code:** Is this conversion correct and if not, how would I correctly convert them? I suspect it's incorrect because somewhere in this conversion the rgb values are getting messed up and that's why the ecb implementation fails to draw an outline.

```
        // 1. Store rgb values into array
        int w = image.getWidth(); // width
        int h = image.getHeight(); // height
        int total_pixels = (h*w);
        Color[] colors = new Color[total_pixels];
        int i = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                colors[i] = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                i++;
            } // end inner for-loop
        } // end outer for-loop
        
        // 2. Convert int array into byte array for encryption
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(colors.length * 4);        
        IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
        intBuffer.put(total_pixels); // This does not except colors as input and is the wrong variable but using it to show what's happening
        byte[] toBeEnc = byteBuffer.array();
```

**After encryption and reversing my process:**

[ECB: Incorrect output, should have a rough outline of the penguin like in the github link attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsS38.png)

[CBC: This is actually correct given the nature of cbc encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCGaY.jpg)

**Additional Code after encryption:** I know this reversal is also probably incorrect but I figured if I can get the inital conversion correct, I will be able to fix this.

```
        byte[] encBytes = cipher.doFinal(toBeEnc);//encrypted byte array
       
        // 4. Convert byte array back to int array
        IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(encBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
        int[] encArray = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
        intBuf.get(encArray);

        // 5. Convert int array into file format
        DataBuffer rgbData = new DataBufferInt(encArray, encArray.length);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(rgbData, w, h, w, new int[]{0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff},null);
        ColorModel colorModel = new DirectColorModel(24, 0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Mark Case\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\tux-enc.png";
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct solution to this problem with a well commented explanation:

```
     public static byte[] convertImgData2DToByte(BufferedImage image) {
      
            int width = image.getWidth(); // Width
            int height = image.getHeight(); // Height
            int[][] result = new int[height][width]; // 2D array initialization 
    
            /* 
            Nested for-loop that iterates through
            every position in img and stores the pixel data from each
            into the 2D int array
             */
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                    result[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
                }
            }

        /*
        Step 2. Convert the resulting 2D array of rgb values 
        into a byte array. This way it can encrypted.
         */
        int sizeOfResult = 0; // Initialization 
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { // Counts each row length to find total number of ints
            sizeOfResult += result[i].length;
        }

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(sizeOfResult * 4); // Memory allocation (each int requires 4 bytes)
        IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer(); // Holds same memory allocation as byteBuffer

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { // Loops through again to store every int into the intBuffer
            intBuffer.put(result[i]);
        }

        byte[] buffer = byteBuffer.array(); // Final byte representation 

        return buffer; // Return value for ImageEncryption class
```